# Mocking Unit tests and dependency injection for static async class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing

I am having a static async cache for contacts list. Inside of the cache I am calling my repository to get data from backend. I want to mock ContactsRepository, but I need to pass repository as a parameter and use dependency injection.

According to the documentation it won't work, because i need an instance of class to use dependency injection.

```
public interface IContactsCache
{
    Task<List<Contact>> GetContactsAsync(int inst, CancellationToken ct);
}

public class ContactsCache : IContactsCache
{
    private static readonly object _syncRoot = new object();
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, Task<List<Contact>>> _contactsTasks = new Dictionary<int, Task<List<Contact>>>();

    public static Task<List<Contact>> GetContactsAsync(int inst)
    {
        return GetContactsAsync(inst, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public static async Task<List<Contact>> GetCodeValuesAsync(int inst, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        Task<List<Contact>> task;

        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            if (_contactsTasks.ContainsKey(inst) && (_contactsTasks[inst].IsCanceled || _contactsTasks[inst].IsFaulted))
            {
                _contactsTasks.Remove(inst);
            }

            if (!_contactsTasks.ContainsKey(inst))
            {
                _contactsTasks[inst] = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    using (var rep = new ContactsRepository())
                    {
                        return await rep.LoadAsync(inst, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                });
            }

            task = _contactsTasks[inst];
        }

        var res = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);

        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            return res != null ? res.ToList() : null;
        }
    }

    Task<List<CodeValue>> IContactsCache.GetContactsAsync(int inst, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        return GetContactsAsync(inst, ct);
    }
}
```

At the end I expect to have this kind of usage, but I can't figure out how to change cache class or any king of other help will be very helpful.

```
[TestMethod]
public async void GetContactAsync_WhenCalled_ReturnCodeValuesCache()
{
    var expected = new List<Contact>
    {
        new Contact() {Instance = 1, Name = "Test" }
    };

    var mock = new Mock<IContactsRepository>()
        .Setup(x => x.LoadAsync(It.IsAny<int>(), CancellationToken.None))
        .ReturnsAsync(new List<Contact>(expected));

    var actual = await ContactsCache.GetContactsAsync(It.IsAny<int>(), CancellationToken.None);

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
}
```

But it can't work and I don't know how to properly write unit test.

I have a lot of such caches where I am using such repositories. Are there any standart or best practise how to unit test static async caches and how to mock repository in this case?

Comment: Does `ContactsCache` need to be static?

Comment: What mocking framework are you using? It looks like Moq but I don't want to put the wrong tag on the question...

Comment: Why even make the class static? Just have it be a normal class. The whole job of DependencyInjection is to provide the cache class instance to any code that requires it.

Comment: yes, i am using Moq

Comment: I need to have it static to use in many places. It is using for cache purpose and it is very usefull to have it static. I can make it as singelton, but not sure if that can help.

Comment: You can't mock your repository because it is not injected into your cache implementation, but instead is created here. `using (var rep = new ContactsRepository())`

Comment: can you please suggest how to do it in the right way? i spent whole day to find any useful resorse to help me with that but with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've closed some doors by making the cache static.

**Quick and dirty solution:**

Since you can't constructor inject your repository, the next best thing would be to pass it to your static method.

```
 public static async Task<List<Contact>> GetCodeValuesAsync(IContactRepository repo, int inst, CancellationToken ct)
```

If you do this it might be a better idea to move the lifecycle management of the repository one level up. In other words move the `using` statement to the caller:

```
using(var repo = new ContactRepository())
{
    await ContactsCache.GetContactsAsync(repo , It.IsAny<int>(), CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Then in your test you would be able to do this:

```
var mock = new Mock<IContactsRepository>()
        .Setup(x => x.LoadAsync(It.IsAny<int>(), CancellationToken.None))
        .ReturnsAsync(new List<Contact>(expected));

var actual = await ContactsCache.GetContactsAsync(mock , It.IsAny<int>(), CancellationToken.None);
```

**Preferrable solutions:**

I'm assuming that your repository is responsible for session management (hence the IDisposable interface). If there is a way for you to separate your repository interface from whatever resources some of the implementations may need to release, you can move to a constructor injection approach.

Your code will then look something like the following:

```
public class ContactsCache : IContactsCache
{
    private readonly IContactRepository contactRepo;

    public ContactsCache(IContactRepository contactRepo)
    {
        this.contactRepo = contactRepo;
    }

    // ...
    return await this.contactRepo.LoadAsync(inst, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
    // ...
}
```

And your unit test will look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public async void GetContactAsync_WhenCalled_ReturnCodeValuesCache()
{
    var expected = new List<Contact>
    {
        new Contact() {Instance = 1, Name = "Test" }
    };

    var mock = new Mock<IContactsRepository>()
        .Setup(x => x.LoadAsync(It.IsAny<int>(), CancellationToken.None))
        .ReturnsAsync(new List<Contact>(expected));

    var cache = new ContactsCache(mock);

    var actual = await cache .GetContactsAsync(It.IsAny<int>(), CancellationToken.None);

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
}
```

You may also consider reversing the dependency between cache and repository. In other words your repository implementation can have a cache. This allows you to choose your caching strategy more dynamically. For example you could have either of the following:

`var repo = new ContactRepository(new MemoryCache<Contact>())`

or

`var repo = new ContactsRepository(new NullCache<Contact>())` <-- if you don't need caching in some contexts.

This approach means that the consumer of your repository does not need to know or care about where the data comes from. This allows you to test your caching mechanism without needing a repository in the first place. Of course if you want to test the repository, you will need to provide it with a caching strategy.

Following this approach also gives you access to a fairly quick solution, since you can wrap your existing static cache with a class like this:

```
public class MemoryCache : ICachingStrategy<Contact>
{
    public async Task<List<Contact>> GetCodeValuesAsync(int inst, CancellationToken ct) // This comes from the interface
    {
        return await ContactsCache.GetContactsAsync(inst, ct); // Just forward the call to the existing static cache
    }
}
```

Your repository will need some work to make it consider the cache before hitting the db/file system/remote resource.

Side note - if you `new` up 'dependencies' you are no longer doing dependency injection.